# can i use time series to analyse this data?

Tags: python, pandas

I can't identify the parameters of a time series so I wonder if a can apply time series analysis on this series

here is the data

```
             a
03/2017      25
04/2017      427
05/2017      42
06/2017      56
07/2017      204
08/2017      28
09/2017      26
10/2017      225
11/2017      84
12/2017      532
01/2018      0
02/2018      665
03/2018      462
04/2018      238
05/2018      84
06/2018      812
07/2018      273
08/2018      364
09/2018      35
10/2018      175
11/2018      182
12/2018      700
01/2019      32
02/2019      0

rolmeanA= df["a"].rolling(window=12).mean()
rolstdA = df["a"].rolling(window=12).std()
plt.plot(rolmeanA, color="black", label='rolmean')
plt.plot(rolstdA, color="green", label='rolstd')
plt.plot(df["a"], color="red", label='A')

plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.ylabel('Quantities')
plt.legend()
plt.title("a Plot")
plt.show()
```

if I can use time series (what or how can i find the stationarity?) 
if you have any solution on how to analyse this series please help me out. 
Any help will be appreciated. if you find question misplaced i will delete it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stationarity, you can use this scipy package to run a ADfuller test:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
result = adfuller(df["a"].values)
```

Check for the p-value in the variable *results* to check if the stationary hypothesis is true or false (with a certain probability). If not stationary, you can try to analyze the time series resulting in the difference of values (instead of the values).

You can also decompose your series into trend and seasonal patterns with this scipy package:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df["a"].values, model = 'additive', freq=1)
decomposition.plot()
```

Try changing the type of model (additive or multiplicative), and visualize your data in order to try to extract some conclusion (what are you after).

There are lots of different analysis, what is your goal? Forecasting? Build a explicatory model? Check correlations? Each goal has lots of different models and solutions, so in order to give you a solution, you should be clear about what you need.

Comment: my goal is to predict the quantities in the future

Comment: You should try ARIMA or SARIMA models, the scipy package has lots of models for time series analysis, you should check the documentation to see examples.

Also, you can check the TBATS library. This tool searches for the best model (the one with the lower AIC) within a certain model space. It supports multiple seasonalities and several parameters, but it is very easy to use.

https://github.com/intive-DataScience/tbats

Comment: If you are new to time series analysis, you should have a little background in understanding what is a good model, do cross-validation, separate the data into training and test data, etc.
If none of the simple models work for you (I forgot to add the simpler ones like ARMA, HW...), you could try more advanced stuff like neural networks (LSTM networks and CNN).

Comment: yeah im new to time series but not to regressions ,svm, acp, kmeans ....

Comment: thank you for your help I'm gonna search for all of these, i will leave it open until ill find what i want  in hope to get more help

Comment: is stationary means that the average is fix ?

Comment: A _stationary_ time series mean that the mean and variance of the trend does not change (drastically at least) over time. Another way to check it it's  plotting the Autocorrelation plot (ACF): if it drops to 0 pretty quickly, your series is stationary.